# Ocultar datos de un desplegable

Tags: css

Estoy trabajando con un plugin llamadao Events+. Cuando creo un nuevo evento para 50 personas, no deja que cada persona que se inscribe sólo pueda seleccionar 1, sale la lista completa de las 50 plazas.
Después de hablar con los creadores del plugin, me dicen que esa opción no la contempla. Había pensado en ocultar todo el número de plazas del desplegable y dejar únicamente la opción 1. 
Sería posible hacerlo con CSS?
les dejo captura del código.
Gracias de antemano[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, por favor, no pongas el código como imagen, en su lugar pon el código como texto para que podamos verlo mejor y ejecutarlo en la propia pregunta. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Como comentario aparte, no termino de comprender el problema, tienes un `select` con 50 valores, pero sólo quieres que puedan seleccionar una opción... entonces, ¿para qué tener un select? Directamente podrías asignarle un valor, ¿no?.

Comment: Hola, podria hacerse con JavaScript explicame un poco la idea por favor.

Comment: Hola Álvaro y AnySlehider. Muchas gracias por contestar. Siento haber adjuntado una imagen. El select debe de tenerlo porque si no es así, no me hace un recuento de las plazas que quedan libres. Ahora mismo acabo de encontrar una manera de hacerlo, se las comparto por si fuera de interés. 
Es un poco engorroso porque hay que hacerlos para cada uno de los valores.

.eventplus-ddl-items option[value="2"]
{display: none;}

De nuevo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ocultar todos los valores excepto el 1 con esta línea:

```
.eventplus-ddl-items option:not([value="1"]) { display: none; }
```

Si no quieres modificar el código del plugin (soluciones como cambiar el tipo de campo de 'select' a 'hidden' con valor '1', marcar la opción con valor '1' como 'selected', marcar todas las opciones que no tengan valor 1 como 'disabled'...) o si existe una validación por la cual no se puedan seleccionar 0 plazas, entonces te bastaría con el código CSS que puse arriba.

Aún así, esta solución podría traerte problemas. Ten en cuenta que aunque ocultes el resto de opciones del desplegable, éstas siguen estando disponibles: Si el usuario no selecciona '1', el valor que tendrá el desplegable será el de la primera opción que tenga (en este caso '0'), aunque esté oculta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, o1dskoo1

Comment: De nada, ¡suerte con el plugin! :)